# Formatting in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Sometimes when I auto format in NetBeans 8+, this is what happens to my code:

```
HBox hBox = new HBox();
```

turns into

```
HBox hBox
            = new HBox();
```

And this happens to all my code. I can't get this extra line break removed.

Which editor setting in NetBeans should resolve this? Or is this a bug?

I figured out how to reproduce it, put two }} brackets before the line of code and run the auto-format shortcut.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
}}
    Double testVariable = new Double(0.0);
}
```

will turn into this after auto-formatting:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
}
}

Double 

testVariable 

= new Double

(0.0);
}
```

Then fix the error (i.e. remove the two brackets), and re-format:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Double testVariable
            = new Double(0.0);
}
```

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem by playing with the formatting settings **(Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting > Language = Java, Catagory = xxx)** without success. The most puzzling part of your question is that you say this only happens "sometimes". Can you clarify when this does or does not happen?

Comment: Found out how to reproduce it....

Comment: OK. I can reproduce your problem with NetBeans Dev (Build 201804200002) and NetBeans 9.0, but not with NetBeans 8.2. What is the exact version of NetBeans that you are using, as shown by **Help > About > Product Version**? Also, although it probably doesn't matter, which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Mine is: Apache NetBeans IDE 9.0 (Build incubator-netbeans-release-334-on-20180708) and Java is JDK SE 8.172  and JRE 8.172

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read message from View - IDE log. Maybe it help you to understand what's happen. 
In most cases it related to syntax error in code.